# Can Traffic pass a trunk if its not allowed but set as native vlan?

Tags: cisco, vlan

If i have configured 3 vlans

- vlan10
- vlan20
- vlan30

and then i make 2 trunkports

```
int gi0/1
description trunk1
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan 20
switchport trunk native vlan 10

int gi0/2
decription trunk2
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan 30
switchport trunk native vlan 10
```

does that allow traffic from vlan10 over these trunks even i have allowed 20 and 30 only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only the VLANs in the VLAN allowed list will pass. In fact, the Cisco security best practices recommend not using VLAN 1 (the default VLAN), not using a native VLAN, and restricting the VLANs allowed to only those actually needed on the trunk.

To that end, you can leave VLAN 1 as the native VLAN and not include it in the `switchport trunk allowed vlan` command. Also, disable the VLAN 1 SVI on any switches.

You should also use the `switchport nonegotiate` interface command on the switch interfaces to disable DTP that can negotiate between access an trunk for the interface.